# Can't update a column using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What am i doing wrong here? I'm trying to update a column (amount), but i get nothing when I call the function--no errors, nothing.

```
function deposit($accountno, $newAmount)
{
  $sql = "UPDATE client SET amount = amount + :newAmount WHERE accountNo = :accountNo LIMIT 1 )";

    $stm = connect()->prepare($sql);    
    $stm->bindParam(':accountNo', $accountno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->bindParam(':newAmount', $newAmount, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stm->execute();           
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you should enable error reporting ...

Comment: Remove bracket `)` in the end of query.

Comment: how embarrassing :) thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have an extra `)` at the end of query string. Change

```
$sql = "UPDATE client SET amount = amount + :newAmount WHERE accountNo = :accountNo LIMIT 1 )";
                                                                                           ^^^
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE client SET amount = amount + :newAmount WHERE accountNo = :accountNo LIMIT 1";
```

Also suggest you to add error reporting (`$stm->errorInfo()`).

Comment: couldn't see the bracket, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** What am i doing wrong here? ... I get nothing when I call the function--no errors, nothing.

**A:** Your code is **ignoring** the error message from MySQL. MySQL is throwing an error, your code is ignoring it. Aside from a syntax error in your statement, all sorts of other errors could occur. After you fix the syntax error, your code is going to "swallow" any other errors that happen.

If you aren't going to include code that checks the return from the PDO methods, you can have PDO perform the checks automatically, and throw an exception when an error occurrs.

(We're not seeing the definition of the `connect()` function in your code, but based on the code you posted, we'd do something like this:

```
$dbh = connect();
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stm = $dbh->prepare("...");
```

Then when a MySQL syntax error occurs, or any other MySQL error occurs when running a SQL statement, PDO will throw an exception, rather than silently ignoring the error.

Comment: It works now, there was a syntax error. thank you for the advice